# 2D Dynamic array in C++

Tags: c++, traversal, dynamic-arrays

If I declare a 2D dynamic array in C++ using the following code:

```
int *arr2D[2];              //allocating rows statically
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
     arr2D[i]=new int[6];   //for each row, 6 columns are dynamically allocated
}
```

Then how should I enter and display values in this 2D dynamic array using loops?
(issues with dynamic array traversal for entering and displaying values in it after its allocation)

Comment: Why on earth are you allocating dynamically? `int arr2D[2][6]` should suffuce.

Comment: By looping, and reading input? I would suggest learning C++ from one of [these books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Comment: You need to use two loops to input and display it: `for(int i(0); i < 2; i++){ for(int j(0); j < 6; j++){  cin >> arr2D[i][j];}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use loops to input the array and display it:

```
int *arr2D[2];

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    arr2D[i] = new int[6];

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for(int j(0); j < 6; j++){
        std::cout << "arr2D[" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
        std::cin >> arr2D[i][j];
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for(int j(0); j < 6; j++){
        std::cout << "arr2D[" << i << "][" << j << "]: "
            << arr2D[i][j] << std::endl;
    }
```

Finally don't forget to free up memory (Memory allocated with `new` must be freed up by `delete`):

```
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    delete[] arr2D[i];
```

Comment: In short, can we say whether we work with static or dynamic arrays, we can enter and display array values using same subscript notation i.e. arr2D[i][j] ??
I am asking this because some approaches assign allocated memory to a pointer variable and then use that pointer to perform array operations.

Comment: like this one:
int *p;
p = new int[10];
*p = 25;
p++; //p points to the next array component
*p = 35;

Comment: No! `p++` will increment the pointer itself. You can if you use it like this: `int* ptr = p; *p =25; p++; *p = 10; p++; ` Now as you can see `ptr` keeps track of the first element. So you can use to walk memory allocated. `p = ptr; while(p) std::cout << *p; p++;` What I recommend use indexes not `C style`: `for(int i(0); i < size; i++) std::cout << p[i];`.

Comment: Yes you use `index` to input and display array elements. Remember that `arrays` are indexed from `0` as the first element to `n - 1` as the last element. Any try to read outside this interval will cause `Undefined behavior`.